# How to change Android system settings via Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, settings, system

I have the following code to change the system accent color:

```
fun sendMessage(view: View){
    val cr = applicationContext.contentResolver
    putInt(cr, "accent_color", "-8270158")
}
```

And `canWrite(applicationContext)` returns true.

My Manifest.xml already has:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

And I've used adb to grant WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS and native settings to "Modify System Settings". I'm still getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot change private secure settings.
```

I can use adb to change the accent_color using

```
adb shell settings put system accent_color -8270158
```

I also tried using shell scripts through Kotlin but they didn't work either. My project uses API 16 and testing device is Android 11.

Comment: are you rooted?

Comment: I'm not, but I know for a fact the Automate (a great tasker alternative) is able to do this without root.